# List acronyms in nomenclature which are not used

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature

Is it possible to have some of the acronyms, which are defined but not used in the text, in the list of nomenclatures (using glossaries package)? Or in other words, how can I add some more entries to the list of nomenclature where the entries are not used in the text.

Example:

Say I have defined two acronyms like following

```
\newacronym[user1={$\AA$}]{ao}{$a_o$}{equilibrium bond length of pure X}
\newacronym[user1={$\AA$}]{a1}{$a_1$}{equilibrium bond length of pure Y}
```

But in the text usual `\gls{ao}` and `\gls{a1}` cannot be used due to particular sentence construction. But as these symbols are there in the equations, so should go to the list of nomenclature.

Thanks.

Comment: What about the `\glsaddall` command before the `\printglossaries` or `\printglossary[type=...]` commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you generate your list of acronyms using the `acronym` option when loading the `glossaries` package, you should try:

```
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
```

where you want it to be displayed in your document. This will add to your list all the entries which are defined but not used. If you also want to suppress the location list in the list you should add the `nonumberlist` option when loading the package.